# Looping Label Change Background task in Swift

Tags: swift, loops

I was looking for a way in Swift to loop a changing label that cycles through an array of Strings. Most ways I've tried have stopped all other tasks while the loop was running.

Comment: How often do you want the label to update its text?

Comment: about every 2 seconds or so

Comment: Okay, take a look at my solution below and change the `interval` constant to `2.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're view controller could look something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cycleLabel: UILabel!

    var strings: [String]!
    var timer: NSTimer!
    var index: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.strings = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit", "Vestibulum", "erat", "lacus", "congue"]
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.cycleLabel.text = self.strings[self.index]
    }

    @IBAction func beginCyclingTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        let interval = 1.0

        if self.timer.valid {
            self.timer.invalidate()
        }

        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: "updateLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateLabel() {
        self.index += 1
        self.cycleLabel.text = self.strings[self.index % self.strings.count]
    }

}
```

This code will update the label text to the next string in the `strings` property every one second. If you'd like a different interval, change the `interval` constant in the `beginCyclingTapped(:)` method. The label will start restart from the beginning of the `strings` array after it reaches the last element in that array. The if statement in `beginCyclingTapped(:)` ensures that multiple timers are not scheduled to update that label, which would result in the label getting updated more frequently than desired. Also, make sure you hook up the `IBOutlet` to a `UILabel` on your Storyboard.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you. Instead of using a button to start I placed the begin cycling in viewDidAppear(), Now I'm looking into a fading change of text in the label.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. Take a look at https://github.com/biasedbit/BBCyclingLabel. It might be what you're looking for. (At the time of writing, I have not contributed to BBCyclingLabel.)